# when i press the button the application gives me an error "index out of range"

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

In this code I dynamically create checkboxes which I populate with data from my database.

My intention is when I press the `btnProba` button to show the text property only from the selected checkboxes. But it gives me an error in this row saying that index is out of range! I can't explain why.

```
lblProba.Text = myche[0];

public partial class FormEGN : System.Web.UI.Page
{
        string mynewstring;
        List<string> myche = new List<string>();
        CheckBoxList mycheckbox = new CheckBoxList();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mynewstring = (string)Session["id2"];

           // lblProba.Text = mynewstring;
            if(!IsPostBack)
            {
                ddlNumberTourists.Items.Add("1");
                ddlNumberTourists.Items.Add("2");
                ddlNumberTourists.Items.Add("3");
            }
        }

        protected void ddlNumberTourists_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int numTourists = Convert.ToInt32(ddlNumberTourists.SelectedItem.Text);

            for (int i = 0; i < numTourists; i++)
            {
                Label myLabel = new Label();
                myLabel.ID = "lblAccomodation" + (i + 1).ToString();
                myLabel.Text = "Настаняване Турист" + (i + 1).ToString();
                Page.FindControl("form1").Controls.Add(myLabel);
                DropDownList myDropDownList = new DropDownList();
                myDropDownList.ID = "ddlTourist" + i.ToString();
                Page.FindControl("form1").Controls.Add(myDropDownList);
                Page.FindControl("form1").Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));

                string connectionString = "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=EXCURSIONSDATABASE;Trusted_Connection=true";
                string query =
          "SELECT Extra_Charge_ID, Excursion_ID, Amout, Extra_Charge_Description FROM EXTRA_CHARGES WHERE Excursion_ID=" + mynewstring;
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    int s = 0;

                    while (rd.Read())
                    {
                        // CheckBox myCheckbox = new CheckBox();
                        //   myCheckbox.ID = "ckbExtraCharge" + i.ToString() + s.ToString();
                        // myCheckbox.Text = rd["Extra_Charge_Description"].ToString();
                        //  Page.FindControl("form1").Controls.Add(myCheckbox);
                        //  Page.FindControl("form1").Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
                        //  s++;

                        mycheckbox.ID = "chkblextracharge" + i.ToString() + s.ToString();
                        mycheckbox.Items.Add(rd["Extra_Charge_Description"].ToString());
                        Page.FindControl("form1").Controls.Add(mycheckbox);

                        if (mycheckbox.Items[s].Selected == true)
                        {  
                            myche.Add(mycheckbox.Items[s].Text);
                        }
                        s++;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { }
            }
        }    

        protected void btnProba_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblProba.Text = myche[0];
        }

        protected void btnReserve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            string num = Request.QueryString["ExcursionID"];
            Response.Redirect(String.Format("ClintsInformation.aspx?Excursiondate_ID={0}",num));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Verify All Columns in DataReader Object are exist in Table and The Names Of Columns In DataBase and Name Passed In DataReader Object are Same.You can fix error by placing a break point in starting positon of each function and step through the code by each statement and verify the values.

Comment: **WHERE** exactly - on what line of your code - does this error happen?

Comment: The line is that lblProba.Text = myche[0];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `ddlNumberTourists_SelectedIndexChanged` is the one that set the `myche` when is find some selected, but the data is lost on the second call where is the

```
 protected void btnProba_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // here is the issue
            lblProba.Text = myche[0];
        }
```

The two calls are happening on different post back.

You need to call the `ddlNumberTourists_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` on button click and not on every change of the dropdownlist, eg I rename it to `CheckWhatIsSelected()` and here is the code:

```
protected void CheckWhatIsSelected()
        {
            int numTourists = Convert.ToInt32(ddlNumberTourists.SelectedItem.Text);

            for (int i = 0; i < numTourists; i++)
            {
                Label myLabel = new Label();
                myLabel.ID = "lblAccomodation" + (i + 1).ToString();
                myLabel.Text = "??????????? ??????" + (i + 1).ToString();
                Page.FindControl("form1").Controls.Add(myLabel);
                DropDownList myDropDownList = new DropDownList();
                myDropDownList.ID = "ddlTourist" + i.ToString();
                Page.FindControl("form1").Controls.Add(myDropDownList);
                Page.FindControl("form1").Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));

                string connectionString = "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=EXCURSIONSDATABASE;Trusted_Connection=true";
                string query =
          "SELECT Extra_Charge_ID, Excursion_ID, Amout, Extra_Charge_Description FROM EXTRA_CHARGES WHERE Excursion_ID=" + mynewstring;
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    int s = 0;

                    while (rd.Read())
                    {
                        // CheckBox myCheckbox = new CheckBox();
                        //   myCheckbox.ID = "ckbExtraCharge" + i.ToString() + s.ToString();
                        // myCheckbox.Text = rd["Extra_Charge_Description"].ToString();
                        //  Page.FindControl("form1").Controls.Add(myCheckbox);
                        //  Page.FindControl("form1").Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
                        //  s++;

                        mycheckbox.ID = "chkblextracharge" + i.ToString() + s.ToString();
                        mycheckbox.Items.Add(rd["Extra_Charge_Description"].ToString());
                        Page.FindControl("form1").Controls.Add(mycheckbox);

                        if (mycheckbox.Items[s].Selected == true)
                        {  
                            myche.Add(mycheckbox.Items[s].Text);
                        }
                        s++;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { }
            }
        }    

     protected void btnProba_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                CheckWhatIsSelected();
                if(myche.Count > 0)
                   lblProba.Text = myche[0];
                else
                   lblProba.Text = "Non selected";
            }
```

One other possible solution is to save the `myche` on viewstate.

Answer (score 0):

Other solution using the ViewState. You use the ViewState to store your selection and you have it after the post back. Do not forget to clear your list on `ddlNumberTourists_SelectedIndexChanged`

```
List<string> myche
{
    get
    {
        if (!(ViewState["cMyChe"] is List<string>))
        {
            // need to fix the memory and added to viewstate
            ViewState["cMyChe"] = new List<string>();
        }

        return (List<string>)ViewState["cMyChe"];
    }
}

 protected void btnProba_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // double check if have something on the list
    if(myche.Count > 0)
       lblProba.Text = myche[0];
    else
       lblProba.Text = "Non selected";
}
```